# best way to run a service periodically in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, handler, alarmmanager

I want to know which is most cost effective way to run a service periodically in android to do certain task say about 'x' hours. Will alarmmanager and broadcast receiver be a good option or else a better alternative would be to use handler. Can somebody suggest something on this and please do post sample code as to how to go about doing by each way using alarmmanager,broadcast receiver and the other by means of a handler.

Comment: I've answered your question, but I wanted to separately address your request for sample code.  Obviously sample code is usually great, but given how general your question is, that request feels like your want someone to do your work for you, or to write you a tutorial, which isn't appropriate.  You can easily find tutorials on using `AlarmManager` via a web search.

Answer (score 2):

`AlarmManager` is the normal way to accomplish "do such-and-such every X hours".  Using a `Handler` isn't really an option for that.